# Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}), f_n(x):=f(x-\frac{1}{n})$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve some real analysis question, and I have no clue how to solve this one.

$$ \text{Let: }f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}), f_n(x):=f(x-\frac{1}{n})$$
$$
\text{Prove that } f_n \text{  converges to } f \text{ in } L^1(\mathbb{R}) \text{ when } n\rightarrow\infty
$$

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but please show some effort.

Comment: Do you know that Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations? That means that $\varphi \in \mathscr{L}^1$ if and only if $\varphi(t - \cdot) \in \mathscr{L}^1$ for all $t \in \mathbf{R}$ (furthermore, the two functions integrate to the same number).

Comment: You mean that $$\mathbb{R} + \frac{1}{n} = \mathbb{R}?$$

Comment: Is the fact that $$n\rightarrow\infty$$ redundant? @WilliamM.

Comment: No, I meant that $\int f(x) dx = \int f(x - \frac{1}{n}) dx.$ But on a second thought, that does not seem to give you convergence in $\mathscr{L}^1.$ You may need to use that you can approximate $f$ by some nice function (e.g. continuous that vanish at infinity) and then for the nice function you can use that the sequence of translations converge _uniformly._

Comment: @WilliamM.
What do you mean by a nice function?
Does approximating by supremum of simple function works here?
Does it help to show that any simple function that approximates f has the same integral of a simple function that approximate $f_n$?

Comment: If you can approximate $f$ in $\mathscr{L}^1$ with a sequence $\varphi_k$ in $\mathscr{C}_0$ (continuous that vanish at infinity) then $\varphi_k(t - \cdot) \to f(t - \cdot)$ in $\mathscr{L}^1,$ so you'd write $$f(x) - f\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right) = f(x) - \varphi_k(x) + \varphi_k(x) - \varphi_k\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \varphi_k\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right) - f\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right).$$
The first and last pairs of functions here converge to zero in $\mathscr{L}^1$ and the second pair _will converge_ to zero uniformly because functions un $\mathscr{C}_0$ are _uniformly continuous._

Comment: @WilliamM.
Thanks!
Why can I approximate $f$ with a sequence of *continuous* function?
$f$ isn't said to be continuous.
Why is it needed for them to vanish at infinity?

Comment: I'm gonna leave it here, you need to also think a bit. Notice the emphasis I placed, try to follow the argument given "if this nice approximation exists, you are done" (why?, what is the crux of the proof?, etc.)

Comment: (By the way, the set $\mathscr{K}$ of continuous with compact support is a subset of $\mathscr{C}_0,$ you may want to _actually approximate $f$ with a sequence in $\mathscr{K}$ rather than in $\mathscr{C}_0$._ This does not matter in your exercise but $\mathscr{C}_0$ is the closure of $\mathscr{K}$ in the space $\mathscr{B}$ of bounded function with the sup-norm.)

Comment: @WilliamM.
It looks like I missed a whole section in my book!
So, any $L^1$ function can be approximated by a continuous function with a compact support, which makes it uniformly continuous.   
Now it all makes sense, since those functions are continuous, when $n\rightarrow\infty$ I can use uniformly continuity, and the equation above works.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and it is called "uniform continuity" by the way.

Comment: @WilliamM.
Yeah, it looked weird to me and I changed it a moment later (not a native English speaker unfortunately)
By missing this section of the book, no wonder I couldn't think of a solution for this question. Thanks again